# SSRS with Stored Procedure containing multiple count statements

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have few lines query which has multiple count statements. I have created Stored procedure for the select count statements and it is giving results when i run it on SSMS but when i use the stored procedure in SSRS it is giving only 1st query output. How do I get other queries output too while using ssrs?

Code from Comments:

```
select count(*) as Field1
from #TempTable1;

select count(*) as Field2
from #TempTable2;

select count(distinct ANo) as F3
from #TempTable1;

select count(distinct BNo) as F4
from #TempTable2;

select count(*) as F5
from Table1
where InsertDate >= StartDate
      and InsertDate <= EndDate
      and value1 >= 2
      and TestField = 0;

select count(*) as F6
from Table1
where InsertDate >= StartDate
      and InsertDate <= EndDate
      and value1 >= 2
      and TestField = 1;

select count(*) as F7
from Table1
where InsertDate >= StartDate
      and InsertDate <= EndDate
      and value1 >= 2
      and TestField = 0;
```

Comment: What is the procedure code? Do you have all of the counts as separate outputs?

Comment: _SELECT Count(*) As Field1 FROM #TempTable1
SELECT Count(*) As Field2 FROM #TempTable2

SELECT Count(Distinct ANo) As F3 FROM #TempTable1
SELECT Count(Distinct BNo) As F4 FROM #TempTable2


SELECT count(*) As F5 FROM Table1 WHERE InsertDate >= StartDate AND InsertDate <= EndDate
AND value1 >=2 AND TestField = 0

SELECT count(*) As F6 FROM Table1 WHERE InsertDate >= StartDate AND InsertDate <= EndDate
AND value1 >=2 AND TestField = 1

SELECT count(*) As F7 FROM Table1 WHERE InsertDate >= StartDate AND InsertDate <= EndDate
AND value1 >=2 AND TestField = 0 _

Comment: I have counts as separate outputs but haven't declared output parameters as I want the code to return fields and values

Comment: `UNION ALL` between each of your selects to combine all the selects into one statement.

Comment: I'm getting output as
Field1
-----------------
Output1
Output2
Output3

Comment: Good news is that I'm atleast getting all values in one column but the column name is displaying as the first column name used in first query

How to get another column which displays its field name before the output value?

Comment: Do you want 1 row with a different column for each result? Or multiple rows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145894/discussion-between-naveen-bodapati-and-jacob-h).

Comment: Why not just select 
(select count(*) as Field1
from #TempTable1) as Field1,

(select count(*) as Field2
from #TempTable2) as Field2,

(select count(distinct ANo) as F3
from #TempTable1) as F3 


etc

Comment: If you create multiple Datasets (procs or scripts) for each of the statements above, your scripts can be run in parallel (maybe) whereas your current script will be executed sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found the answer

Here is what I've done
Declared local variables and used them as below in query

select @A= count(*) from Table1
Select @B= count(*) from Table 2

Select @A as Field1,@B as Field2

This gives the output in single row.